# Customize list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I want to make list of listings a bit different than what it gives by default. 
For example for figures, I used package `tocloft`. It worked ok, I was wondering if `tocloft` could do the same for list of listings.
I want it for example just like this:

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure 20\quad}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.5cm}
\listoffigures
```

I already used the following lines:

```
 \renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Programs}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Programs}
 \lstlistoflistings
```

But I want, in this case when the list is displayed to be for example Program 1.1  instead of 1.1 alone. How could I do this??

Thanks,
Claude

Comment: `tocloft` hooks into the standard `ToC` etc and the `list of ....` somethings that are generated by `tocloft` itself, but not in a `float` package generated `ToC`, which is the case for `listings`. You're out of luck here if `tocloft` is applied directly.

Comment: is there another specialized package for list of listings????

Comment: Not as far as I know, but I've got an idea -- give me some time, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `float` package is not used, `listing` 'hi-jacks' the `\@starttoc` command and 'pretends' to typeset the  `ToC` -- since this is all done in a group, the real `ToC` is not affected by this.

`tocloft` itself can't change such `list of...` that are not provided by the package itself or one of the standard classes.

The following code changes the `\l@lstlisting` command definition and inserts the word 'Program' before the listing number. `\l@lstlisting` is doing the same like `\l@section` etc.

The original definition in `listings.sty` is

```
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}}
```

The `1.5em` width indicates the indentation, the `2.3em` is meant for the width of the number box. Since `\l@lstlisting#1#2` is redefined within a `\renewcommand`, I've to use `##1` and `##2` instead of `#1` and `#2` only.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{\bfseries Program ##1}{##2}}
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{First}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My nice program},language=C]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your solution for my project. I've added `\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{LIST OF LISTINGS}` inside `AtBeginDocument` block to change TOC string but it didn't work. Is there any quick solution for this?